# Is there name for statistical thinking of -- say a basket of 60% red, 40% black balls --- NOT guessing optimally?

Tags: expected-value, fallacy

I remember reading about this.
Say there's a basket of 60% red balls and 40% black balls.

And many statistical laymen if say given a reward for a correct guess -- they will guess red and black and etc. Although obviously the maximum "expected value" move is to guess 100% red every time.

Is there a name for this particular statistical fallacy?

Comment: If you have to guess each ball in turn (without replacement) for the whole bag, and the reward is for getting all the guesses correct rather than for each correct guess, and if you know the percentages are exact for the balls in the bag rather than independent probabilities), this is the only way to win anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One "strategy" or phenomenon that is sometimes observed in these cases is called [probability matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_matching) - which, in your example, would be to guess red 60% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of [probability matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_matching): saying "red" 60% of the time and saying "black" 40%?