# Classifying an Event Based on Time of Day

Tags: probability, classification

My problem is very simple:

Say I am running a hotel, and I want to make an educated guess on whether a guest is a business or leisure traveler.  The guest does not tell me if they are business or leisure until check-out, but I want to make my guess at check-in time.  All I know at check-in time is the time itself.  I have many years of historical data, and there appears to be somewhat strong correlation between check-in time and traveler class.

*What is the appropriate technique for this classification?*

Simple probabilities per hour does not seem to work, although I can't quite wrap my head around why. Each hour makes sense in isolation, but when I evaluate it across 24 hours of data, it is selecting business travelers 3x more often than it should.

I think a Poisson distribution would almost work except that the rate of arrivals for each class varies by hour.

**Edit**
It's been pointed out in the comments that I've been unclear. My intention is not to guess correctly as often as possible, but rather to statistically model the guest population based on check-in time, before it is known which class they belong to. In other words, taking the known population of current guests, and classifying them based on check-in time.

**Edit 2**
The ultimate question I want the model to answer is "At any given time, what are the counts of leisure guests and the counts of biz guests currently staying with us." This can only be determined through some statistical process, because each guests' class is not known until the guest leaves, but we have lots of retrospective data to draw from and there is correlation between check-in time and class.

Comment: If you want to predict the probability of 1 individual being a business traveler you can try logistic regression. If you want to predict the number of business travelers in a certain period of time, Poisson is an option. Not sure what you tried but probabilities per hour is not really a valid concept

Comment: How granular is your check-in time data? Do you only have access to the hour or do you have it in terms of (functionally) continuous times?

Comment: @fmtcs My understanding was that logistic regression assumes linearity between the dependent and independent variables, and probability by hour of day is not linear. Am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: @PhysicsKid Check-in times have second granularity. I truncate to the hour simply for smoothing purposes.

Comment: That is a misunderstanding.  However, logistic regression might be overkill.  If you were to plot the fraction of business travelers checking in on a rolling basis, say within a 15 minute window, you would clearly *see* the relevant information.  The issue of what to guess, though, is different. For instance, if you want to be correct as often as possible, then you should always guess business when the historical frequency is 50% or greater and otherwise guess leisure.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576691 might be relevant.

Comment: @whuber I think you are suggesting what I would probably suggest (if not let me know) which is that you could bin the data in some relevant bins that have large enough sample size to be reliable and then just predict based on whichever has a higher historical frequency in that bin.

Comment: @PhysicsKid Just about anything along those lines ought to work, given the amount of data.  A smooth, a spline, etc would likely all closely agree with the simple binning approach. What we lack, though, is the *loss function* implicit in this question.  I posted my comment in the hope that it might elicit some information about the consequences of deploying this classification.

Comment: Why do you have the `[poisson-process]` tag here?  Why are you thinking about the Poisson distribution?  In general, for classification, you'd use something like logistic regression (as noted).  I'm wondering if there's more to your real situation than your cover story.

Comment: I apologize... I see now that I'm being somewhat unclear. My intention is not to guess correctly as often as possible, but rather to statistically model the guest population based on check-in time.  In other words, modelling as accurately as possible the number of guests from each class that have not checked out yet. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I cannot (yet) see any difference between those two objectives.  Could you tell us what the result of an ideally performing "statistical model" would be, if not to maximize the frequency with which it guesses correctly?  (After all, that's what any binary classifier is supposed to do.) For instance, maybe you want your model to provide a *probability* that any new visitor is a business traveler?  (That would be solved with a logistic regression against a spline of the time of day, for instance.)

Comment: @whuber Please bear with me... stats is not my area, which is why I'm here :). The ultimate question I want the model to answer is "At any given time, what are the counts of leisure guests and the counts of biz guests currently staying with us."

Comment: It seems like the path stated by whuber makes the most sense for the problem as you have stated it. A poisson process gives you counts of random arrivals, but you HAVE arrivals you just want to classify these individuals in a particular way. This classification can be done simply (with binning and then taking the highest class) or slightly more ~probabilistically~ with a logistic regression where your features are the splines for the time of day (and then again taking the highest probability class)

Comment: That's much clearer!  You don't want to "classify" anything: you want to *model occupancy.*  A good model would exploit data you have about the amount of time each visitor stays and might even capitalize on other information such as the day of the week, proximity to holidays or local special events, and even the preceding level of advertising.

Comment: Do you know anything else?  Do you know check out times?  Do you know the number in each party?  Do you know if the room is a single or double?  Etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. I am pursuing the earlier suggestion of a logistic regression against a spline of time of day.

Comment: @whuber, my intention was to derive occupancy from a "check-in time" model + "stay duration" model, where both are strongly correlated to leisure/non-leisure. The classification that we're discussing would be one step of this larger model.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica All we know is check-in time

Comment: Is this really a hotel, or something else?  How is it possible you don't know when people checked out, etc?  Do you know how many rooms there are in the hotel?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Yes, as stated above, check-out reveals more information, including the time of check-out, and the class of traveler. But at check-in time, only time is known. The classification needs to occur prior to check-out. Room count is also known at any time.

Comment: But you should be able to use that information as part of the dataset to train the model.  When someone checks in, you only know *their* check in time, but you also know the check in times over the previous days, & some of those guests will have checked out (which you should also know).  It should be possible to have a running total of guests in the hotel when a new guest checks in.  That's 99% of your occupancy.

Comment: "Simple probabilities per hour does not seem to work [...]. Each hour makes sense in isolation, but when I evaluate it across 24 hours of data, it is selecting business travelers 3x more often than it should." - are you by any chance classifying each guest as business or leisure according to which is most likely given his hour of arrival, then totting up your classifications to estimate the no. leisure & business guests? That won't work: add the probabilities. (You'll encounter the same issue with logistic regression on a continuous predictor.)